# How do I sync my music and video from iTunes to new iPhone 6?

Tags: itunes, iphone

In trying to sync my music and video to my new iPhone 6, I noticed that all of the music and videos that I purchased downloaded to my new phone but all of the ones that I had ripped from CDs did not. Is there a way to sync all of my music and videos from iTunes to iPhone 6? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Its simple.

- Open iTunes.
- Connect the iOS device to your computer using the
  included USB cable.

[image: Locate your device]

- After clicking on your iOS device, tabs appear on the left side of the iTunes window under Settings.
- You can turn on syncing for Music, Movies, TV Shows, Podcasts, Books, Audiobooks, Tones, Photos, and Info. To turn on syncing, click the content type from the list under settings, then click the box next to Sync [content type]. If there's a check in the box already, syncing is turned on for that tab. To turn off syncing, uncheck the box.

[image: Sync Music]

- Click the Sync button in the lower-right corner of the screen to sync your content. Only the information in the content list you've enabled syncing for will sync to your computer. If you made any changes to any of the settings, first click the apply button.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to sync the contents of your old iPhone to a new phone is contingent upon your backup method. If you have an iCloud-based backup, you may find the following article helpful:

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4036

If you've been backing up your iPhone to iTunes, the basic idea is the same; erasing setting and data from the phone, which then causes the phone to prompt whether you wish to configure it as a new phone or restore from backup. Restoring the phone from backup will import all your existing data.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766

Answer (score 0):

Plug in the new iphone to iTunes, then select the iPhone within iTunes. Click on the Music tab, and chouse 'Sync all music..."